# How to get back freebox tv in VLC 2.1.0 and above?

Tags: vlc-media-player, tv

Since version 2.1.0 VLC is missing the option to view Freebox TV channels (for Freebox clients in France), which was visible in Playlist - Internet - Freebox TV.

Is it possible to get that back?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option in the playlist as present in the previous versions was provided by an addon called 'freebox.luac' situated in the `lua/sd` folder.

So, download from the VLC archives a portable (archived) older version (2.0.8) which still contains that file  - [here](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/) - 2.0.8  is [**h e r e**](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/2.0.8/) - and copy the freebox.luac file into  the corresponding folder of your latest VLC installation.

[image]

---

Also, VLC can open playlists - including TV playlists. The one for Freebox TV is [here](http://tvsurpc.en-direct.tv/playlist-free.zip).

One can of course create a playlist after getting the freebox addon by opening Playlist - Internet - Freebox TV, and, selecting all stations in the list, or just some of them, right-click, 'Add to playlist'.)

Comment: [nightly builds](http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/win32/?C=M;O=D) 2.2 and 3.0.0 now have the addon back. the testing version 2.2 from [here](http://download.videolan.org/testing/vlc-2.2.0-pre3/win32/) does not